# Help me sex this Endler's livebearer

Tags: aquarium, fish, biology, anatomy, gender-differentiation

[image]

It looks like a female (no colors and round belly), but it seems to have a gonopodium organ, a dot on the tail-fin that other females lack and the gravid spots near its vent are fainter and higher up than other females.
Males occasionally display in front of it but they chase after it less than after other females.

Here's another picture:
[image]

Comment: i did not answer this question when it was first posted,because no answer will be correct.it is probably both genders at the same time and is most likely sterile,the reason for this happening is probably a result of a hormone imbalance during development,this can be caused by chemicals in the environment or by cancer in the mother fish(the same thing can happen in mamals too humans included).

Answer (score -1):

The best way to discern male from female is by looking carefully for that gonopodium you spotted. That is a male sex organ and you'll not find it on a female.
In short, that is a male fish.
Late reply, I know. Hopefully he's still happily living in your tank and this helps somewhat.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Would you please add some kind of source? Did you have one of them yourself? Do you have a website or book or paper where one could read more about this in fish?

Comment: @BlakeCass personal experience is also acceptable.